# Web server URL access from outside LAN

Tags: php, url, ip, webserver, host

My question is, in the dashboard, the URL (Local IP & port) Is the URL that i have to access from outside the LAN? Do i have to redirect something to make an other configuration?

Comment: You wish to access your development webserver from outside your LAN is that what you mean? And by `outside your LAN` - within the same network or over the internet?

Comment: No. over the internet. I mean, the URL that give me the web server is mi pc ip with the port number, is that ip that i use to access over internet? Or i need some DNS configuration? Thank you RamRider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local server environment can be configured using following services for accessing through internet.

All are free service:

```
http://localtunnel.me/
https://ngrok.com/
http://localhost.run/
```